# ¿Cómo puedo mandar los datos que tengo en localstorage a mi base de datos con ajax?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Esto guarda datos en localstorage:

```
$(function(){         
   $('#boton1').on('click',function(){
      var n = document.forms.f.nombre.value;
      var ed = document.forms.f.edad.value;
      var es = document.forms.f.estatura.value*100;
      var pe = document.forms.f.peso.value;

      var fecha = new Date();

      if(b==0){    
          c = '{"nombre":"'+n+'","edad":'+ed+',"es":'+es+',"pe":'+pe+'}';
          b=1;
      }else{    
          c =c+ ',{"nombre":"'+n+'","edad":'+ed+',"es":'+es+',"pe":'+pe+'}';

          localStorage.setItem('d','{"personas":['+c+']}');
          reg1 = localStorage.getItem('d');
          reg = JSON.parse(reg1);
      }            
    });
 });
```

Ahora como guardarlos en una base de datos.

Comment: Hola Eckiel, bienvenido a Stack Overflow. ¿Puedes ser un poco más específico sobre qué base de datos tienes exactamente?

Comment: Esta pregunta es demasiado amplia tal como está formulada. Constaría de varias partes: 1) cómo enviar datos al servidor (implicaría probablemente usar ajax y recoger los datos con php, la respuesta dependería de las librerías javascript que usaras) y 2) cómo guardar esos datos en base de datos (la respuesta variaría según la estructura de base de datos y el motor de base de datos que usaras). Lo que necesitarías es un tutorial, y stackoverflow no es adecuado para eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por encima, ya que es muy compleja tu pregunta.

Haz una petición Ajax usando método POST con los datos de `reg1` en PHP los puedes obtener usando la función `$_POST[]` debes revertir los datos obtenidos que están en formato json, con la función `json_decode` lo puedes hacer y obtendrás un arreglo estructurado, que los puedes recurrir con un `foreach` y llenar tu base de datos

Comment: Hola entonces  quedaria Asi?  $(function(){
       $('#boton').click(function(){
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "guardar.php",
        data: {
          data : localStorage.getItem('d')
        },

        success: function(data) {

            $('#iframes').html(data);
        if (data == '1') {
          $('#iframes').html('correcto');
        }else{
          $('#iframes').html('Error');
        }

        }
          });

      });
    });